# Getting billing/shipping address issue in Magento 1

Tags: magento-1, shipping-address, billing-address

This is my code:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getCollection();
foreach ($collection as $customer){
          $defaultBilling     = $customer->getDefaultBillingAddress();
          $defaultBilling2   = $customer->getPrimaryBillingAddress();
          $defaultShipping    = $customer->getDefaultShippingAddress();
}
```

In all of the 3 cases I'm getting `false` or `null`. The all idea is that i want to check which customers has a default billing address and doesn't have a default shipping address or vice versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try with customer address model `Mage_Customer_Model_Address`:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('customer/address')->getCollection();
//var_dump((string)$collection->getSelect());
foreach ($collection as $address){
    /** @var Mage_Customer_Model_Address $address */
    $customer = $address->getCustomer();
    $defaultBilling     = $customer->getDefaultBillingAddress();
    $defaultShipping    = $customer->getDefaultShippingAddress();

}
```

See more here: [How to Check If given address is Default Shipping or Billing address using Address id Magento](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/117472/how-to-check-if-given-address-is-default-shipping-or-billing-address-using-addre)